# Rust rdkafka BaseConsumer can't poll data

Tags: rust, apache-kafka, rust-rdkafka

I'm new to rust. Trying to read some data from kafka with rdkafka doesn't work. This is the most basic form of reading from kafka and it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use log::{info, warn};
use rdkafka::{ClientConfig, ClientContext, Message, TopicPartitionList};
use rdkafka::config::RDKafkaLogLevel;
use rdkafka::consumer::{BaseConsumer, CommitMode, Consumer, ConsumerContext, Rebalance, StreamConsumer};
use rdkafka::error::KafkaResult;
use simple_logger::SimpleLogger;

fn main() {
    SimpleLogger::new().init().unwrap();
    let context = CustomContext;

    let consumer: BaseConsumer<CustomContext> = ClientConfig::new()
        .set("group.id", "test4")
        .set("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:29092")
        .set("enable.partition.eof", "false")
        .set("session.timeout.ms", "6000")
        .set("enable.auto.commit", "true")
        //.set("statistics.interval.ms", "30000")
        //.set("auto.offset.reset", "smallest")
        .set_log_level(RDKafkaLogLevel::Debug)
        .create_with_context(context)
        .expect("Consumer creation failed");

    consumer.subscribe(&["tserlc-20230805"]).unwrap();

    let r = consumer.poll(Duration::from_secs(3))
        .expect("Poll failed")
        .expect("KafkaResult failed");
}

struct CustomContext;

impl ClientContext for CustomContext {}

impl ConsumerContext for CustomContext {
    fn pre_rebalance(&self, rebalance: &Rebalance) {
        info!("Pre rebalance {:?}", rebalance);
    }

    fn post_rebalance(&self, rebalance: &Rebalance) {
        info!("Post rebalance {:?}", rebalance);
    }

    fn commit_callback(&self, result: KafkaResult<()>, _offsets: &TopicPartitionList) {
        info!("Committing offsets: {:?}", result);
    }
}
```

I get following logs in my rust console:

```
2023-08-05T20:48:55.704Z TRACE [rdkafka::client] Create new librdkafka client 0x7fffe6562620
2023-08-05T20:48:55.704Z TRACE [rdkafka::util] Destroying topic partition list: 0x7fffe6561750
2023-08-05T20:48:55.704Z TRACE [rdkafka::util] Destroyed topic partition list: 0x7fffe6561750
thread 'main' panicked at 'Poll failed', src/main.rs:38:10
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225/library/std/src/panicking.rs:593:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225/library/core/src/panicking.rs:67:14
   2: core::panicking::panic_display
             at /rustc/8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225/library/core/src/panicking.rs:150:5
   3: core::panicking::panic_str
             at /rustc/8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225/library/core/src/panicking.rs:134:5
   4: core::option::expect_failed
             at /rustc/8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225/library/core/src/option.rs:1932:5
   5: core::option::Option<T>::expect
             at /rustc/8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225/library/core/src/option.rs:898:21
   6: market_data::main
             at ./src/main.rs:37:13
   7: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
2023-08-05T20:48:58.769Z TRACE [rdkafka::consumer::base_consumer] Destroying consumer: 0x7fffe6562620
2023-08-05T20:48:58.769Z TRACE [rdkafka::consumer] Running pre-rebalance with Assign(TPL {tserlc-20230805/0: offset=Invalid metadata="", error=Ok(())})
2023-08-05T20:48:58.769Z INFO  [market_data] Pre rebalance Assign(TPL {tserlc-20230805/0: offset=Invalid metadata="", error=Ok(())})
2023-08-05T20:48:58.769Z TRACE [rdkafka::consumer] Running rebalance with Assign(TPL {tserlc-20230805/0: offset=Invalid metadata="", error=Ok(())})
2023-08-05T20:48:58.769Z TRACE [rdkafka::consumer] Running post-rebalance with Assign(TPL {tserlc-20230805/0: offset=Invalid metadata="", error=Ok(())})
2023-08-05T20:48:58.769Z INFO  [market_data] Post rebalance Assign(TPL {tserlc-20230805/0: offset=Invalid metadata="", error=Ok(())})
2023-08-05T20:48:58.773Z TRACE [rdkafka::consumer::base_consumer] Consumer destroyed: 0x7fffe6562620
2023-08-05T20:48:58.773Z TRACE [rdkafka::util] Destroying client: 0x7fffe6562620
2023-08-05T20:48:58.773Z TRACE [rdkafka::util] Destroyed client: 0x7fffe6562620

Process finished with exit code 101
```

And in kafka followings:

```
2023-08-06 00:18:55 [2023-08-05 20:48:55,713] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Dynamic member with unknown member id joins group test4 in Empty state. Created a new member id rdkafka-56c93d6a-b85d-4493-b76c-ee209fa76fb7 and request the member to rejoin with this id. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
2023-08-06 00:18:55 [2023-08-05 20:48:55,715] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group test4 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-40) (reason: Adding new member rdkafka-56c93d6a-b85d-4493-b76c-ee209fa76fb7 with group instance id None; client reason: not provided) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
2023-08-06 00:18:58 [2023-08-05 20:48:58,715] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group test4 generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-40) with 1 members (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
2023-08-06 00:18:58 [2023-08-05 20:48:58,719] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment received from leader rdkafka-56c93d6a-b85d-4493-b76c-ee209fa76fb7 for group test4 for generation 1. The group has 1 members, 0 of which are static. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
2023-08-06 00:18:58 [2023-08-05 20:48:58,770] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group test4 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-40) (reason: Removing member rdkafka-56c93d6a-b85d-4493-b76c-ee209fa76fb7 on LeaveGroup; client reason: not provided) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
2023-08-06 00:18:58 [2023-08-05 20:48:58,771] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Group test4 with generation 2 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-40) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
2023-08-06 00:18:58 [2023-08-05 20:48:58,772] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Member MemberMetadata(memberId=rdkafka-56c93d6a-b85d-4493-b76c-ee209fa76fb7, groupInstanceId=None, clientId=rdkafka, clientHost=/172.18.0.1, sessionTimeoutMs=6000, rebalanceTimeoutMs=300000, supportedProtocols=List(range, roundrobin)) has left group test4 through explicit `LeaveGroup`; client reason: not provided (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

This is a little bit frustrating since this is very basic and I can't see where im missing or what i'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure that you are using the most basic form, since `BaseConsumer` has been [pointed here](https://docs.rs/rdkafka/latest/rdkafka/consumer/struct.BaseConsumer.html) as : _A low-level consumer that requires manual polling._  I can't see anything in documentation but according to [code](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/blob/v0.33.2/src/consumer/base_consumer.rs#L137)  if it can't find any data in 3sec(I assume that min queue poll interval is 1sec) it just returns `None` and unwrapping `None` causing panic

Comment: You can start with the examples provided, if you are seeking the basics https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/blob/v0.33.2/examples/simple_consumer.rs

Comment: @Ömer Erden. Thanks. given example is by StreamConsumer and uses tokio which in my use case is overkill. i want a simple client. in addition can you describe this log to me:
[market_data] Pre rebalance Assign(TPL {tserlc-20230805/0: offset=Invalid metadata="", error=Ok(())})
on rebalance call back logs. what is the meaning of `error=Ok(()). also kafka that im using has tons of data so poll in 3 sec cant return without any data.

Comment: I don't know, I am not familiar with this crate, but as the documentation suggest you have to call poll periodically. The poll you have called will do nothing if it cant receive any data in 3 seconds. You can use  `consumer.poll(None)` to create a simple example, it will block the thread until data is received.

Comment: Also, without auto.offset.reset=earliest, then it'll poll from the end of the topic, where there's no data without an active producer